# default_attributes - Chef

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have an attribute defined in cookbook as:

```
default[appName]['releasePackageURL'] = "https://nexus.abc.com/Test/.1/web-.8.zip"
```

I also have a `default_attribute` under environment as below:

```
default_attributes": {
  "wwwRoot" : "C:\\Websites",
  "ABC" : {
    "version" : "ABC0.0.0.1_Release",
    "releasePackageURL" : "https://nexus.abc.com/Test/.1/web-.8.zip"
  }
}
```

The value for `releasePackageURL` is getting duplicated in both environment and in cookbook. How can this be avoided?

Answer (score 2):

Attributes when defined stay in the respective definitions. So the attribute being present in both places cannot be avoided (since you have defined it). But when chef-client is run the attributes are evaluated for precedence https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html and the right attribute value is provided to the chef-client. In your case, the value from environment attribute will be picked up.

Comment: Thanks for your response.                                                                            I am new to chef.  What is the order of execution for chef scripts?

Comment: It's explained in the link provided by Amod. Section "Attribute Precedence".